# Drop Down list dictated by Check Box in excel

Tags: excel, checkbox, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a quoting tool for work and i want to simplify the process. we quote 5 carriers that have around 70 plans each. Each carrier has a drop down list.  I was wanting to add some checkboxes on my input page that would coordinate with drop down menus on the quote page. Is it possible to have a check box dictate a certain list in a drop down menu so i can narrow down which options would automatically populate on my quoting tool?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you're looking for:

[image: Dynamic Dropdown]

**Step 1** - Insert an ActiveX Check Box in cell A1 and change the following properties:

```
Caption:    (blank)
Height:     12
Left:       1.5
LinkedCell: C1
Top:        3
Width:      12
```

This will link the Check Box to cell C1.

**Step 2** - Resize column A to a width of 2.

**Step 3** - In cell D1, put `=IF(C1,B1,"")`.

**Step 4** - Copy row 1 and paste it into rows 2 & 3.

**Step 5** - Change the properties of the two new Check Boxes so the `LinkedCell` matches the Check Box's row.

**Step 6** - In cell F2, add Data Validation to allow a "List" with the Source as `=$D$1:$D$3`.

This will reproduce what I have in the image above. You can adapt this to your workbook as necessary. The dropdown list will only populate with the values that are checked. However, it will insert blank values where the values are unchecked. If this is a problem, you can use some VBA to make the dropdown more dynamic.